# complete disk access for TeXShop on a Mac with Catalina

Tags: mac, mactex

I asked a basic question a couple days ago, and someone referred me to a previous post which solved the problem (kudos to you.. thanks) but this leads me to a couple more questions.

My previous question was that TeXShop would only typeset a latex file if it was in my Desktop directory, and the solution was to allow TeXShop full disk access under Privacy settings.

I noticed that:  /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin
has been added to my $PATH.

Did this come from installing MacTex, or installing TeXShop?

(It seems this is still in my $PATH whether or not TeXShop has full disk access.
Should this be the case?)

Also, just curious: is this full disk access an issue with TeXShop for the mac OS
versions that come after Catalina?

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Mactex adds the paths. No idea about the access setting though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @daleif said, the PATH setting is added when you install MacTeX. The full disk access issue is the result of Apple adding more security features to the macOS ecosystem over the past several years. Apps are supposed to request permission to access your disk and TeXShop must do just that. It should be a one time thing to set the first time the app is used.

Comment: Hey thanks.  You were the one that answered my first question.   I got my machine running Catalina, upgraded to BigSur, and then my logic card broke, and I had to ship it to apple, where they replaced the card, wiped the drive and it came back with Catalina.  I then reinstalled and added many Apps.  This is the first time I have seen this particular issue with any app.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm very glad to have helped. If my answer is satisfactory, you can accept by clicking the check mark.